# how to store n number of employee attendance data a ta time with their id in another table as any other column name

Tags: php, laravel

[image]

Model 1

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class employee_attendence extends Model
{
    //

```
protected $fillable  = array('is_present' ,'date' );
//protected $fillable=[];
public $timemstamps= false ;

public function employee_data(){
        //return $this->hasOne(employee_data::class,'App/employee_data');
    return $this->hasOne('App\employee_data');

}
```

}
model 2

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class employee_data extends Model
{
    //protected $fillabel=['first_name','last_name','contact_no','date_joining','post'];

```
protected $fillable  = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'contact_no' ,'date_joining','post' );
//protected $fillable=[];
public $timemstamps= false ;

public function employee_attendence()
{
        //return $this->hasOne( employee_attendence::class, 'App/employee_attendence');
        return $this->belongsTo('App\employee_attendence');
}
```

}

controller

```
public function Attendence() 
{
    $data=employee_data::all();
    return view('attendence',compact('data'));
}   

public function mark_attendence(Request $request)
{

    $request->validate([
    'date'  =>  'required',
    'is_present'  =>  'required'

    ]);

    $employee = new employee_attendence([
    'is_present' => $request->get('is_present'),
    'date' => $request->get('date')

    ]);


$employee->save();
$employee->employee_data()->create([]);

return redirect('/index')->with('succ','Attendence Added Successfully');


}
```

form

```
<table class="table table-bordered  ">
    <tr>
        <th width="5%">Id</th>
        <th width="15%">First Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Last Name</th>
        <th width="15%">DateOfJoining</th>
        <th width="10%">post</th>
        <th width="15%">Date</th>
        <th width="10%">Remark</th>
        <th width="30%">Action</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach( $data as $row )
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $row->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->first_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->last_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->date_joining }}</td>
            <td>{{ $row->post }}</td>
            <td><input type="date" value="CURDATE()" name="date"  ></td>
            <td>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Present" name="is_present" value="Present">&nbsp &nbsp Present 
                </label><br>

                <label class="form-check-label" for="radio2">
                     <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Absent" name="is_present" value="Absent">&nbsp &nbsp Absent
                </label></td>


            <td>

            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></button>


            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
```

store id from table 1 as user_id in table2

Comment: What exactly you want?

Comment: i want to add attendance of all the employees i will register through add new employee tab at a time with their respective unique user_id